# Why fonts in IOS 5 not displaying as bold as they are in IOS 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am building an application which is IOS 5 compatable...I am able to resolve all compatability issues expect the fonts...the fonts are not looking as bold as they are in IOS4...Thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: First of you question isn't very constructive, what have you tried, how are you loading and displaying the text. So some code.

Answer (score 0):

I am noticing the same thing, my vision isn't what it used to be and I thought it was due to fatigue but I too last night observed the same thing..... akin to lowering the contrast and sharpness on a LCD screen.

any fixes?